# Как сделать "генерацию" Embed в discord.py?

Tags: discord, discord.py

В своём дискорд боте я хотел сделать команду, которая бы выводила Embed с заданными значениями и мой код с самого начала был таким:

```
@bot.command(pass_contest=True)
async def embed(ctx, title1, field_name, field_value):
    emb = discord.Embed(title=title1, color=0xfca7fc)
    emb.add_field(name = field_name, value=field_value,inline=False)
    await ctx.channel.send(embed = emb)
```

Но немного задумавшись, я понял что не смогу задавать значения больше одного слова.
Помогите мне, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я понял, вам нужно, чтобы функция принимала в аргумент `field_value` не только одно слово, но и всю остальную часть сообщения.

Для этого перед аргументом в параметрах функции нужно указать `*`:

```
async def embed(ctx, title1, field_name, *, field_value):
```

Теперь при команде `!embed Заголовок Название значение 1 2 3 4 5`, аргументы примут следующие значения:

```
title1      = 'Заголовок'
field_name  = 'Название'
field_value = 'значение 1 2 3 4 5'
```